# dates on which procedure was updated before

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008 database. i am developing an application which tracks the changes made in the database related to procedures and functions.

i need dates on which changes was made in the procedure.
i tried using following code but it gives me last update or create date.
but i want all the dates on which i was made changes in the procedure.

```
   SELECT name,modify_date  
   FROM sys.objects  
   WHERE type = 'P'  
   AND DATEDIFF(D,modify_date, GETDATE()) < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't permanently stored anywhere.

Recent schema modifications are in the [default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/determining-how-a-schema-change-occurred/10718#10718) but you would really need to create a [DDL trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.105).aspx) to 
log this yourself.